# why doesn't getBoundingClientRect serialise with JSON.toStringify?

Tags: javascript, json

Try this in dev tools console:

```
JSON.stringify(document.body.getBoundingClientRect())
```

the output is {}, instead of something sensible.

Any ideas?

Comment: cause getBoundingClientRect returns textRectangle: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMClientRect, not js object

Comment: yeah but its typeof object

Comment: typeof returns "object" not only for js objects but for most enviroment objects too. I remember this part of spec but to lazy to search for prooflink)

Comment: try "typeof document.body" for example

Comment: ok what would you suggest, just manually convert it to an object by accessing the props of the clientrect?

Comment: Note that `Object.keys(document.body.getBoundingClientRect())` returns `[]` for the same reason. It means manually creating a JS object with those properties (or using object destructuring, which is essentially the same thing).

Comment: yes, just manually convert

Comment: WontFix: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=498538

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON.stringify internally uses a method called [toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior).

You can specify it for your object or in your case, override it:

```
ClientRect.prototype.toJSON = function(){ return { top: this.top } }

JSON.stringify(document.body.getBoundingClientRect())

"{"top":-583}"
```

Comment: money patch, nice!!

Comment: Could you guys be more constructive? :)

Comment: @Caramiriel every somewhat experienced js developer knows, that changing native prototypes is _generally_ very bad practice. It is like timebomb for applications larger then todolist. Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice